# Сокрытие определения шаблона (C++)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, header, library

Возможно ли скрыть тело шаблона, как это делается при раздельной компиляции заголовочного файла и реализации (т.е. пользователю предоставляется бинарник и заголовок).
Например, пишется проприетарная библиотека шаблонов и необходимо предоставить пользователю только заголовки обобщенных функций и классов.
А если невозможно, то какие методы для выхода из ситуации?

Comment: Для полноценного использования шаблонов пользователю должно быть доступно их определение.

Comment: Если предполагается, что пользователь должен инстанцировать шаблоны со своими типами, то определение шаблона должно быть доступно. Если же набор типов конечен и известен, то можно явно инстанцировать шаблоны с нужными типами.

Comment: макмально близкое к ответу на твой вопросу можешь посмотреть тут, https://youtu.be/_AkF8SpUV3k но без объяснения цели не понятно что именно ты хочешь

Comment: Невозможно, придется позориться :) Не то в 98, не то в 03, стандарте такое пытались сделать, но все тихо умерло, так как реализовано было только каким-то одним компилятором, и то, кажется, не полностью. Если ваш шаблон должен работать для очень ограниченного множества типов - в принципе можно... но тогда с тем же успехом можно просто сделать соответствующий набор обычных классов/функций, не дергая шаблоны.